# How to evaluate methods of another class in current context?

Tags: ruby, reflection, delegates, metaprogramming

I have 2 classes whose object should act as "partners". The first one is my `Thing` class, whose instances should act as `Tree::TreeNode`s of the gem RubyTree.

Basically, this delegation can be implemented using `Forwardable`:

```
class Thing < NoClassInheritancePlease
  extend Forwardable

  def initialize(title = "node")
    @node = Tree::TreeNode.new title

    # Collect node methods that should be delegated
    node_methods = @node.public_methods(false)
    node_methods += @node.protected_methods
    node_methods -= (public_methods(false) + protected_methods(false) + private_methods) # own methods should not been delegated

    # Set up delegation of specified node methods as singleton methods
    for method in node_methods
      Base.def_delegator :@node, method
    end
  end
end
```

**Problem:**
A number of `TreeNode` methods refer to `self`. For example:

```
def each(&block)             # :yields: node
  yield self
  children { |child| child.each(&block) }
end
```

Thus, `my_thing.each {...}` yields `self`, i.e. the `Tree::TreeNode` object that belongs to `my_thing` but not the `Thing` object itself.

Another example:

```
siblings = []
parent.children {|my_sibling| siblings << my_sibling if my_sibling != self}
siblings
```

parent.children returns an Array of `Thing`s and therefore the condition never evaluates to false as `my_sibling` is a `Thing` (which is fine) but `self` is a `Tree::TreeNode`

**Question**: *How to evaluate the instance methods of a class (e.g. `Tree::TreeNode`) in the context of another class (e.g. `Thing`)? ("overwrite self")*

I tried with UnboundMethods, but you can only bind an instance of the original receiving class to an unbound method.

Comment: Are you really sure there's no other way? Your approach seems... flawed.

Comment: Well, no other way than copying&pasting or not using the methods. I think I will fork RubyTree one day to make it delegatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want, [you could use evil-ruby](http://code.google.com/p/evil-ruby/) to solve this.

```
require 'evil'
class A; def m; self; end; end
class B; end
A.instance_method(:m).force_bind(B.new).call
```

Comment: Thanks! So I know my options. 

What an evil library! xD Even allows for multiple inheritance.

I think I will fork RubyTree one day to make it delegatable. Probably the less-evil solution.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `instance_exec`.

From the docs:

> Executes the given block within the context of the receiver (obj). In order to set the context, the variable self is set to obj while the code is executing, giving the code access to obj’s instance variables. Arguments are passed as block parameters.

```
class KlassWithSecret
  def initialize
    @secret = 99
  end
end

k = KlassWithSecret.new
k.instance_exec(5) {|x| @secret+x }   #=> 104
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Object.html#method-i-instance_exec

In your case you can use instance_exec to yield self.

```
def each(&block)
  instance_exec{ yield self }
  children { |child| child.each(&block) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can.  Maybe with instance_eval {unboundmethod.to_proc} or something?

Comment: Apparently, you cannot coerce an UnboundMethod to Proc.

`NoMethodError: undefined method `to_proc' for #<UnboundMethod: Tree::TreeNode#each>`